# How to change only the cursor of datepicker & timepicker

Tags: java, android

Java Code to datepicker:

```
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
  CreateGroupEventActivity.this,
  urdate,
  cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
  cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
  cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Theme for my Activity:

```
<style name="ForSignUpPage" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- customize the color palette -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/forWhenAppGoesBackGround</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorDashboardBlackLayer</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

        <item name="android:textColorHint">#ffffff</item>

        <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
```

These three lines I am using for white shade to `TextInputLayout`:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
            <item name="colorControlActivated">#ffffff</item>
            <item name="colorControlHighlight">#ffffff</item>
```

If i am changing

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">#ffffff</item>
```

to the color `#000000` I am achieving. But same field i need for white shade to `TextInputLayout`.

If it is white color `#ffffff` cursor is also changing to white color.

[image]

I just want to change the cursor color .